# Android check reboot time adb

Tags: android, adb

Is there an adb command that I can use to check when did a device reboot? I know you can figure this out in application code, but I just want to be able to shell in, run a command, and see how long the device has been booted for, or an actual timestamp for the last reboot event.

Comment: `adb shell cat /proc/uptime`

Comment: The timestamp of the root directory seems like it is *plausibly* the boot time of the device I just checked - ie, `adb shell ls -ld /` but no idea if it's reliable.